# Get woocommerce attribute label translation from WPML (hook)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I'm trying to get the translation of some woocommerce global attributes. I have the IDs and the slugs of the attributes but I'm not able to find a way to do it.
So far I have tried with these filters:

- *wpml_object_id*
- *wpml_translate_single_string*

But I cannot find the correct `$element_type` for the *apply_filters* function.

For example here:

```
apply_filters('wpml_object_id', $attribute->id, $element_type, FALSE, $current_language_code);
```

WPML Hooks Reference: https://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-coding-api/wpml-hooks-reference/#hook-605256